# Does Manometer Tubing Size Affect Measurements?

Tags: hvac, furnace, gas, natural-gas

Does the diameter & length of tubing used with a digital manometer affect gas pressure readings? I'm trying to measure the outlet gas pressure going into my furnace and I had to connect different diameter sized tubing together to connect/fit to my digital manometer's ports.

I'm not sure however whether the readings are skewed by this or by the length of the tubing. I'm assuming the tubing length doesn't matter, not sure about tubing diameter though.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Pressure drop is caused by gas *flowing through* a restriction such as a narrow / long piece of tubing. Once the system reaches equilibrium (i.e. the manometer is pressurised), there is no gas flow and therefore can be no influence on the measured pressure.

The diameter / length of the tubing is therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

A manometer is usually used to measure vacuum. Vacuum measurements ARE affected by both diameter and distance.
I may be taking this to an extreme but high tech equipment has the gauge attached directly to the chamber the more accurate readings needed the larger the connection size. The vacuum pumps are as close as possible and cryogenic pumps are mounted directly on the chambers for most equipment.
Vacuum has a real limit because there is only 14 psi or the lack of to work with so distance creates a problem as higher vacuum levels are reached.  So depending on the distance and vacuum level yes both size and distance matter.

With hvac equipment it is not as significant but it will affect the reading.
Even the position of the pressure port can affect the measurements by 10% and the reading can be higher or lower depending on conditions and locations.
So yes size length and position matter in an hvac system.
Positive pressures not so much.